# voice search in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone

i saw some applications in other mobiles , when i say something like "apple"(through voice), that application will search apple related information from google and shows them.is it possible in iphone sdk?

Answer (score 1):

Voice commands are included in iOS, but there is no public API for developers to hook into.  Instead, you'll need to work with a third party framework to implement this feature - I would recommend looking at Nuance (the makers of Dragon Dictation).  It looks like they have an API and framework that you can use, but I'm assuming there is a licensing cost.

http://www.dragonmobileapps.com/developers.html